# Error: Mismatch of Closure Arguments expected fn(&static _) found fn(_)

Tags: debugging, rust, syntax

I am getting this type error and I cannot figure out what is wrong code below:

```rust
use std::{collections::{HashMap, btree_map::Values}, any::TypeId};
#[macro_use]
use lazy_static::lazy_static;

pub fn constraint_eq(x: &f32, y: &f32) -> f32 {
    (x-y).abs()
}

pub fn constraint_neq(x: &f32, y: &f32) -> f32 {
 
    match x != y {
        true => 0.0,
        false => (x-y).abs()
    }
}

pub fn constraint_lt(x: &f32, y: &f32) -> f32 {
    match x < y {
        true => 0.0,
        false => (x-y).abs()
    }
}

pub fn constraint_gt(x: &f32, y: &f32) -> f32 {
   match x > y {
        true => 0.0,
        false => (x-y).abs()
    }
   }

type ConstraintFn = fn(&f32, &f32) -> f32;

lazy_static! {// 
    pub static ref OPERATORS: HashMap<String, fn(&f32, &f32) -> f32> = {
        let mut m = HashMap::new();
        m.insert("==".to_string(), constraint_eq as ConstraintFn);
        m.insert("!=".to_string(), constraint_neq as ConstraintFn);
        m.insert("<".to_string(), constraint_lt as ConstraintFn);
        m.insert(">".to_string(), constraint_gt as ConstraintFn);
        m
    };
}

pub struct Constraint{
    // EQUALS: &'static str = "==0"
    // 
    EQUALS_ZERO: &'static str,
    LESS_THAN_ZERO: &'static str ,
    GREATER_THAN_ZERO: &'static str,
    op: &'static str,
    // function: fn(&f32) -> f32,
    function: Box<dyn Fn(&'a f32) -> f32>
}

impl Constraint{
    pub fn new(op: &'static str, value: Option<f32>) -> Constraint {
        let EQUALS_ZERO: &'static str = "==0";
        let LESS_THAN_ZERO: &'static str = "<0";
        let GREATER_THAN_ZERO: &'static str = ">0";
        // let op: &'static str;
        if value.is_some() {
            
            let op = &format!("{}{}", &op, &value.unwrap().to_string());
            let function = Box::new(move |x:f32| OPERATORS[op](&x, &value.unwrap()));         

            return Constraint {EQUALS_ZERO, LESS_THAN_ZERO, GREATER_THAN_ZERO, function, op}

        } else {
            let op = &format!("{}{}", &op, &0.0.to_string());
            let function = Box::new(move |x:f32| OPERATORS[op](&x, &value.unwrap()));         
            return Constraint {EQUALS_ZERO, LESS_THAN_ZERO, GREATER_THAN_ZERO, function, op}
        }
        
        }
        

        pub fn call(&self, value: &f32) -> f32 {
            (self.function)(value)
        } 
        // Constraint {EQUALS_ZERO, LESS_THAN_ZERO, GREATER_THAN_ZERO, function, op}
        }
```

I am trying to get a partial function of it becoming a closure, but sure how to fix this error.
the error that I am getting is :

```
|             let function = Box::new(move |x:f32| OPERATORS[op](&x, &value.unwrap()));         
    |                                     ------------ found signature defined here
101 |
102 |             return Constraint {EQUALS_ZERO, LEQ_ZERO, GEQ_ZERO, LESS_THAN_ZERO, GREATER_THAN_ZERO, function, op}
    |                                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^ expected due to this
    |
    = note: expected closure signature `fn(&'static f32) -> _`
               found closure signature `fn(f32) -> _`
    = note: required for the cast from `[closure@src/constraint.rs:100:37: 100:49]` to the object type `dyn Fn(&'static f32) -> f32`
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can this be fixed? I

I tried incorporating lifetimes but I have been running into an error. I switched from `fn(&f32)-> f32` to `Box<dyn Fn(&'a f32) -> f32>`

Comment: The definition of `OPERATORS` seems relevant but is not here. Please read [mre] and provide one.

Comment: Am I missing something? You've defined that `function` should be `Box<dyn Fn(&'a f32) -> f32>` (i.e. a `&f32` parameter), but the closures you're constructing are `move |x:f32| ...` (i.e. explicitly declaring a `f32` parameter). One of these have to change.